# Whatsapp web in webview by using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, jsoup

Unable to load Whatsapp  web URL using  android Jsoup library and here I am using this code.

```
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String url = "https://web.whatsapp.com";
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .header("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)  // Add your User-Agent here
                        .get();
                final String htmlData = doc.html();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        webView.loadData(htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8");
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Exception", "run: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

basically I need to change Whatsapp web UI by using Jsoup because jsoup providing some build in function to hide the divs in the webview

Comment: No way you can do this with Jsoup. Jsoup doesn't execute JavaScript and this page seems to rely on JS.

Comment: yes you are right i did with an other way like WebView providing like 
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display='none';");